# how to start service from fragments

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to start service from fragment from a list view item. I am trying to call service with:

```
startService(new Intent(getActivity(),myPlayService.class));
```

But it wont work at all. How do i call my service from fragments? Is there any another way to start service?

Comment: What doesnt work? Be more clear? Doesnt it start? does it crash? Does it work if you start it within the activity?

Comment: it shows red line on startservice(); and when you mouse over it it show you option like create method startservice()... how do i call service from fragment?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Replace

`startService(new Intent(getActivity(),myPlayService.class));`

with

`getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),myPlayService.class));`

Comment: But it wouldn't even compile anyway if he didn't use getActivity()

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, that's what the original post was saying. They were asking how to make it compile.

Answer (score 3):

To start service from a fragment use

Java

```
requireActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(), ServiceName.class));
```

Kotlin

```
requireActivity().startService(Intent(context, ServiceName::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the service tag in manifest.xml

```
   <service android:name=".ServieName"/>
```

The service won't start if the service tag is not properly added in the manifest.

For more info [refer android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Declaring)